# ImageMagick Reduces Colorspace to Gray

Tags: imagemagick, rgb, grayscale

I convert RGB and CMYK TIFF images to RGB JPEGs using

```
convert a.tif -colorspace rgb a.jpg
```

If the TIFF image contains only gray pixels, the colorspace of the resulting JPEG is gray, not RGB.

How can I force ImageMagick to always use RGB?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
convert a.tif -colorspace rgb -type truecolor a.jpg
```

However, I have to ask: **How exactly do you determine your verdict *'colorspace of resulting JPEG is gray, not RGB'*?!?**

The ImageMagick tool `identify` can look at the colorspace used by files. If you have `convert`, then you'll have `identify` too:

```
identify -format "%[colorspace]   <== %f\n"  *.png *.jpeg *.pdf *.tif
```

Example output:

```
 sRGB   <== fullsize-coalesce-originals.png
 Gray   <== tiffg4.tif
 CMYK   <== cmyk.pdf
 CMYK   <== photoshop.jpeg
```

Comment: Works, tanks! Gimp says that the image mode is grayscale.

Comment: You legend! Adding the `-type truecolor` with `-colorspace rgb` worked perfectly!