# How to prevent ImageMagick.NET from changing color space on write

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick.net

Attempting to open an image, set its resolution, and save it, and I'm running into an issue where the `ColorSpace` is being modified without any input on my end.

The input image is a blank sRGB/8 image, checking `img.ColorSpace` after creation shows `sRGB`, however after setting the density, writing the image to disk, and opening the output, the `ColorSpace` is set to `Gray`.

```
using (var img = new MagickImage(inputImagePath))
{
    img.Density = new Density(parameters.HorizontalResolution, parameters.VerticalResolution);
    img.Write(outputImagePath);
    // img.ColorSpace is sRGB
}

using (var imgCheck = new MagickImage(outputImagePath))
{
    // imgCheck.ColorSpace is gray
}
```

The downstream code requires the colorspace on the output image to be the same as the input image's. Is there a parameter for `MagickImage.Write()` that can preserve the color space?

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing this related question: [ImageMagick: convert keeps changing the colorspace to Gray. How to preserve sRGB colorspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696728/imagemagick-convert-keeps-changing-the-colorspace-to-gray-how-to-preserve-srgb) it appears that if the image's format is set to `MagickFormat.Png`, and its content is grayscale, ImageMagick sets the color space to grayscale.

```
using (var img = new MagickImage(inputImagePath))
{
    img.Density = new Density(parameters.HorizontalResolution, parameters.VerticalResolution);
    img.Write(outputImagePath, MagickFormat.Png00);
    // img.ColorSpace is sRGB
}

using (var imgCheck = new MagickImage(outputImagePath))
{
    // imgCheck.ColorSpace is gray
}
```

Manually setting the MagickFormat on `Write()` to `Png00` persists the input's color space and bits per pixel setting.