# R Magick Package Image_Write Saves Tiff Images in Gray Instead of RGB

Tags: r, imagemagick

I have a very large number of images that need to be cropped slightly (by 1 pixel either height-wise or width-wise) in order to do further image-processing on them.

I'm trying to use the Magick package in R to do so, but running into an issue where any images that are gray are saved by Magick in grayscale instead of RGB. I see that people have asked similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696728/imagemagick-convert-keeps-changing-the-colorspace-to-gray-how-to-preserve-srgb) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443725/imagemagick-reduces-colorspace-to-gray), and I have tried the solutions offered to no avail. For some reason, when doing Image_Write, setting the defines colorspace to auto-grayscale off and type to truecolor does not work and the images are still saved as grayscale instead of RGB format.

Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
crop <- function(a,b) {
  image <- image_read(a)
  cut <- image_crop(image, b)
  image_write(cut, path = a, format = "tiff", defines = c('colorspace:auto-grayscale' = 'false', 'type:truecolor' = 'on'))
}

runcrop <- mapply(crop, mydat[,1], mydat[,2])
```

Where the input (mydat) is a table with two columns: the path to the image and the pixel size I need the image cropped to. Any image taken in black and white (CH4) is saved as a grayscale output, while all the other channels are correctly saved as RGB images after cropping.

Here is a small excerpt from the table:

```
> mydat
     imtocrop                            WxH            
[1,] "./01 10245 XY01_Fused_CH1.tif"     "2288x1218+0+0"
[2,] "./01 10245 XY01_Fused_CH2.tif"     "2288x1218+0+0"
[3,] "./01 10245 XY01_Fused_CH3.tif"     "2288x1218+0+0"
[4,] "./01 10245 XY01_Fused_CH4.tif"     "2288x1218+0+0"
[5,] "./01 10245 XY01_Fused_Overlay.tif" "2288x1218+0+0"
```

And here is an example image to recapitulate the error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8m93vflnf6rd6ao/01%2010245%20XY01_Fused_CH4.tif?dl=0

The cropping formula I've written works perfectly, but I can't seem to get Image Magick to save these tiffs as RGB instead of grayscale. I've tried both 'false' and 'off' for auto-grayscale, I've tried 'true' and 'on' for truecolor. I've also tried using only the truecolor option, without the colorspace option (as suggested on ImageMagick's documentation site [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/defines.php)). Nothing I do seems to convince Image_Write to output as RBG instead of grayscale. Please let me know if you have any ideas that might fix this error, thanks!

Comment: I think you want `'type' = 'truecolor'` but it's not really a *"define"*, it's more of a *"setting"* I think, and I have no idea where the R documentation for **ImageMagick** lives that would let me see the options.

Comment: Your image is grayscale. If you want to save as RGB, then you have to set the colorspace to sRGB. (and keep type=truecolor)

Comment: @MarkSetchell Unfortunately, write_image does not take type or colorspace as an argument, so I have to use the defines statement as far as I can tell

Comment: @fmw42 The format of my original image is RBG, not grayscale (despite the image being literally gray)

Comment: I opened your image in Photoshop and it said it was grayscale.

Comment: I also opened it in EXIFTOOL and it also indicates that it is grayscale. "SamplesPerPixel: 1"

Comment: @fmw42 Yes, you're right- when I download off of dropbox back to my computer it says grayscale, sorry about the confusion. Not sure why it got changed by uploading to dropbox... In any case, the original file on my computer is listed as RGB.
Edit: Okay, I think I corrected on Dropbox- now when I download back to my computer it says RBG

Comment: OK. That file is indeed now RGB (3 channel, 8-bits). What are your colorspace options.  Have you tried either sRGB or RGB?

Comment: I think I found the documentation, and I think you can set `'colorspace', 'rgb'`

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge of R, but am trying to move my knowledge of **ImageMagick** towards your knowledge of R and maybe we an reach the target of sorting out your problem somewhere in the middle...

Let's make a simple 640x480 solid black image with **ImageMagick** in the Terminal, and pipe it into `exiftool` in TIFF format to check its depth and whether it is greyscale or colour:

```
magick -size 640x480 xc:black tif:- | exiftool - | grep -E '^Bits|^Photometric'

Bits Per Sample                 : 16
Photometric Interpretation      : BlackIsZero     <- means GREYSCALE
```

Ok, not surprisingly, our black 640x480 rectangle came out in greyscale with 16-bits per sample because my **ImageMagick** was compiled with Q16. Let's rectify the 16-bit-edness:

```
magick -size 640x480 xc:black -depth 8 tif:- | exiftool - | grep -E '^Bits|^Photometric'

Bits Per Sample                 : 8              <--- that's better, 8-bit
Photometric Interpretation      : BlackIsZero    <--- still greyscale
```

Ok, now let's force the black image to become RGB:

```
magick -size 640x480 xc:black -type truecolor -depth 8 tif:- | exiftool - | grep -E '^Bits|^Photometric'

Bits Per Sample                 : 8 8 8
Photometric Interpretation      : RGB
```

---

My hope is that you can find the corresponding settings/switches/options in **R Studio** now that you know what they look like.

Another option might be to *"shell out"* with `system()` and just use the command-line interface:

```
magick INPUT.TIF -crop WIDTHxHEIGHT+xoffset+yoffset -type truecolor RESULT.TIF
```

---

Note that I am forcing TIFF format and piping to `exiftool` for simplicity of demonstration. If you are testing in your Terminal, you can write straight to a TIFF file with:

```
magick -size 640x480 xc:black image.tif
```

You can also set lossless compression with:

```
magick -size 640x480 xc:black -compress LZW image.tif
```